# Firebird and Entity Framework Transaction Rollback

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, firebird, rollback

I need to use a Transaction Scope with Entity Framework 4 and a Firebird database. I am using the FireBird Entity Framework provider.

My problem is that once SaveChanges has been called on an object, the data is persisted to the database, instead of when transactionScope.Complete() is called. This results in data never rolling back, even if an exception occurs inside the using (TransactionScope ...) block.

This seems to be a problem with the FireBird DB, I have tested the exact same code with MS SQL 2008 and RollBack works correctly.

What do I need to do to enable Rolling Back with FireBird?

```
using ( var context = new Model1Container() )
        {
            bool success = false;
            using ( TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope() )
            {
                PERSON person = new PERSON();
                person.NAME = "test";
                context.AddToPERSON(person);
                context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);  
                success = true;
                //transactionScope.Complete(); If this line is not hit, Transaction should Roll Back, but it does not.
            }

            if ( success )
            {
                context.AcceptAllChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have auto commit in your connection string?

Comment: Is there a way to set auto-commit=false in the EntityClient connection string?

Comment: Somewhere in the entity client connection string is a plain old connection string look for the "connection string=" inside the entity client connection string.

Comment: The Firebird .Net Provider doesn't seem to make provision for any autocommit options in the connection string. I also can't find any example on the web. I tried various permutations of "autocommit=false" but it seems to be ignored. Is there perhaps a way to set autocommit options in code, using the FireBirdSqlClient?

Comment: Could you post your connectionstring?

Comment: `<add name="Model1Container" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;provider connection string=&quot;initial catalog=PATH_TO_DB.FDB;data source=SERVERNAME;user id=USER;password=PASSWORD;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>`

Comment: Try adding somewhere between the two &quot Enlist=True;

Comment: Added the answer as answer ;)

Comment: @Zpock, please add BennyM's answer as right answer

Answer (score 3):

For firebird you need to explicitly say that it has to participate by adding Enlist=True in the connectionstring.